# Sum of logarithmic series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

Let $x_1>0$ we define sequence $(x_n)$ with formula $x_{n+1}=-\ln(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n)$
Find sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$.
How to deal which such summation with logarithms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We note that the argument of the $\ln$ is just a partial sum of the series.  We know that if the series converges, the terms must converge to zero, so the argument of the $\ln$ must go to to $1$, so the sum must go to $1$.

To establish convergence, we are given $x_1 =\sum_{n=1}^1 x_n \gt 1$ as the base case of an induction.  Assume $\sum_{n=1}^k x_n \gt 1$  Then $x_{k+1} \lt 0$ so the sums are decreasing and $\sum_{n=1}^{k+1} x_n =\sum_{n=1}^k x_n-\ln (\sum_{n=1}^k x_n)\gt \sum_{n=1}^k x_n-( \sum_{n=1}^k x_n-1)=1$ where we used that $\log (1+y) \lt y$.  As the sum is decreasing and bounded below, it converges.

Comment: Brilliant! $\ \ $